# PHP In Angular 2 Template Index.php

Tags: angular

How would I get PHP to show up in an Angular 2 template? My main file is index.php

My use case would be to show the user that is logged in.

```
template: `
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
  ?>
  <h1> <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?> is logged in</h1>
}
?>`
```

Currently my website is just showing all of this as static text and not running it as php code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because it uses the cache version of the template file you loaded previously. You can disable the cache in the controller so that it will always reload the  template file and not use the cache version of it. You have TO =>  import { RuntimeCompiler} from 'angular2/src/compiler/runtime_compiler'; THEN => constructor(private _runtimeCompiler: RuntimeCompiler) AND PUT IN CONSTRUCTOR => this._runtimeCompiler.clearCache();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.  PHP is backend/server side language, while angular uses javascript fronted/client side.

If you need to combine these two languages, you would have to include javascript/angular in your php rather than including php in your javascript/angular.

Answer (score 1):

You can. For examle, in my example project with Laravel 5 and Angular 2, all angular 2 templates will called through Laravel 5 router. All A2 templates is blade.php templates.

And PHP work fine in this templates.

Look at example project: https://github.com/sanex3339/laravel-5-angular-2-example

Comment: I think the OP was referring calling PHP on the Angular2 templates, as seen in his example above.  This would not be possible unless, as  you have mentioned, use a webserver (backed) to parse the PHP together with the angular template as you have done.